# Height above sea level measurement

Tags: gps, altitude, assisted-gps

I would like to use height above sea level in the gravity equations. What is the source for getting it? Can i use altitude measurements from Altimeter or GPS 'z' measurement? For your kind information, I am going to use this for aircraft velocity estimation.

Comment: What is the required accuracy? As for GPS altitude data, they are referenced to the WGS84 ellipsoid. If you need above sea level values, you will have to correct using the EGM (Earth Gravitational Model) data.

Comment: Can you send me the EGM? I am using the gravity vector=[0 0 g] which will be multiplied with direction cosine matrix.

Comment: Google is your friend... http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/index.html